# Titan graph database issue with bulk loading for any datasource

Tags: database, graph, titan

I am very new to Titan Graph database. Please let me know can we perform bulk loading in titan db using Batch Graph for any format of files(example: pdf, doc, xml, xls, csv and etc).
Kindly, please reply if anyone knows about it.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Kamal Verma

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to Titan, you should not be looking at `BatchGraph` for data loading because that is a Titan 0.5.x (and TinkerPop 2.x) concept.  If you are "new" you should be looking at Titan 1.0 (and TinkerPop 3.x):

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/

Titan takes its bulk loading cues from TinkerPop which utilizes the `BulkLoaderVertexProgram` also known as [BLVP](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#bulkloadervertexprogram)

BLVP and [ScriptInputFormat](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#script-io-format) provide you all the flexibility you need to load line delimited data (i.e. for csv, json, xml, etc each line is a vertex).  That obviously won't help you with data held in pdfs and word documents.  You would have to pre-process those into line-delimited format to be able to load them in this fashion.

I highly recommend that you focus on learning TinkerPop before getting too deep into Titan.  TinkerPop is a large ecosystem in and of itself and having a solid basis in that will make it possible to understand the nuances of Titan.  I would suggest you start by reading the TinkerPop [Getting Started Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/tutorials-getting-started.html) before progressing further.

For what it is worth, if you are stuck on Titan 0.5.x for some reason, you can use `BatchGraph` for loading all the data formats you mentioned, but it does not offer a method to do so natively.  You would have to write a script to parse each of those formats and convert it to vertices/edges that would be loaded through `BatchGraph`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for your reply. I am working on Titan version - 0.5.4.

Comment: Hi Stephen,
Thanks a lot for your help and yes for sure I will go through these documents as you have suggested. Currently we are working on Titan version 0.5.4. 
Thanks & Regards,
Kamal Verma